# Not able to debug script task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

In my SSIS package, I have a `script task` in addition to other tasks.  When I put a debug point within the `script task` and run the package( on the whole), ideally, it is supposed to hit the breakpoint. but it now only opens a new VS window, shuts it after few seconds and a green tick is displayed over the task.

I tried setting the the `Run64BitRuntime` flag to false and also editted and saved the script task again. The issue persists. Any pointers on this ?

I have VS 2010 BI and the machine is 64 bit Windows Server R2

Comment: Yup. The pitfall of SSIS. I've never been able to debug a script task. I wonder if there's a workaround for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [how debug a script component in SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446619/how-debug-a-script-component-in-ssis)

Comment: Solution Explorer -> Project -> Properties -> Debugging -> Run64BitRuntime -> False

Answer (score 8):

Yes, break points do work in script task. But if that was a script component, then it wouldn't have worked. Any way, if you have a script task, the reason it might not be working is that it may be using the 64 bit runtime. Try running it in the 32 bit runtime.

Also, make sure that the place at which you have hit the breakpoint is actually reachable. If there are some case statements or if conditions, possibilities are that the line of code is actually missed.

Comment: Starting with the 2012 release of SSIS, you do have the ability to debug script components.

Comment: My first step with the VTSA editor is add a breakpoint at the first line just to get into debug mode and then F5 my way to the actual breakpoint I want.

Comment: Even when i place the breakpoint at the first line, it does not hit the breakpoint. not sure why it does not work now . Already tried the Run64BitRuntime option

Answer (score 3):

Surely debug is allowed for script task. Couple of point to remember
1. Run the package in 32 bit
2.wherever u set up debug pointer... code should be rechable
3.debug only allowed for 1 script task. Ssis engine can only show you debugging only for 1 script task. If you have 2 script task then ssis will open debugging only for first script task.. suggesting you put de bugging only to one script task

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well and found the script task had been set to optimize code even for debug mode.

See more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42382093/469637)