# SSIS Components NOT hitting Breakpoints

Tags: ssis, breakpoints

I have an SSIS package configured for SQL Server 2016.  I have a multiple packages in a project.  In one of the packages, I have some SQL tasks, Script tasks, foreach loop container etc... They are all on the control flow.  I have put pre-execute breakpoints and breakpoints on each start of the iteration for the foreach loop container.. NONE of the breakpoints will trigger.  I can hit breakpoints on the inside of my script tasks, but other than that, I am not able to hit anything.

In my googling, I found something that said to change the Run64BitRuntime setting to false.  (project properties -> configuration properties -> Debugging section)  I set that, saved, restarted my computer, closed and opened visual studio etc.... built, rebuilt, removed the bin/obj files... nothing works.  There have been articles that I read that suggest that setting will fix the issue, but they typically are always referring to breakpoints in the script task, not in the control flow.

Anyone have any suggestions?

[Debugging SSIS Script task - Breakpoint is enabled but it does not hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470415/debugging-ssis-script-task-breakpoint-is-enabled-but-it-does-not-hit)

Comment: I finally found the answer....https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/710c4865-bc74-4f1d-a3b9-865109ee25c7/debugging-problem-with-break-points-not-being-picked-up?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: when you execute a container it will NOT hit the breakpoints... you have to execute the package.  Kind of a pain... not sure why it works this way, but at least I can debug the package.